# There is no export android package file in Xamarin 4.2

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-community

After update Xamarin in Visual Studio to 4.2 version, there is no "Export Android Package" option, instead of it there is "Archive" option, and when I use archive to create package it just create an unsigned package.Where is "Export Android Package" in new version???

[image]

[image]

Comment: Under the `Tools` menu :  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/visual-studio-xa-4.2.6-to-6.1/Images/08-publish-application.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality has been replaced with the new "Archive" functionality.

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.2/#publishing

This now closely mimics the current behavior in Xamarin Studio.

Once you sign the `.apk` you will be prompted to save the `.apk` to place of your choosing:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/#_Sign_the_APK_

You will then be able to view previous archives.

**Documentation:** https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/